# How to structure a ruby plugin?

Tags: ruby, plugins

I want to write an open source plugin, but I have no idea about the structure of it. I read some plugins code on github but sometimes they are hard to understand for me (I'm new to ruby).

Can somebody advise me some links to simple plugins, books, tutorials or anything else to teach me how I can write a well-formed ruby plugin?

Comment: Hi Theo, no more a ruby plugin it's an API parser. What I hope to learn is how to structure the folders and modules not so much the creating a gem.

Answer (score 1):

I think first of all you should learn the language. I'm using ruby for at least 2 years and I'm still learning.

So writing a plugin while being a newbie it's not really a good idea.

But anyway here is an example to build a `gem`:

http://buzaz.com/index.php/2010/01/03/how-to-build-a-ruby-gem/

Comment: thanks, and yeah you're right. What was your way to get better skills?

Comment: Usually I learn in an autodidactic way. I choose a task and I'm trying to solve the problem with the selected language. It works for me.